Edits going Straight to DEFAULT instead of remaining in own version when using Reconcile and Post
We have user doing Traditional Versioning in ArcGIS Pro. User has enough access to make Edits, Reconcile & post to own version which Esri recommends. But when user is making Edits in Feature Class and run reconcile and Post, it doesn't remain in their own version but it directly goes to Default Version which we don't allow and want as well.

DEFAULT version is "Protected".
Named Versions are set to 'Public'.
SQL Server DB is on 2019 version. SQL DB is not using 'dbo' schema. it's using own schema 'gis' and user account is authorized on 'gis' schema.
ArcGIS Pro version:3.2.2

We have analyst, who has higher permission then user and they do the final review & make post to DEFAULT version after review.  I have changed their permission to same as user. Analyst have created their own version. But their Edits after Reconcile and Post process also directly going to DEFAULT instead of remain in their own version.
Has anyone faced same issue and have workaround to share?

We have Middle layer of version which we call it VARIANT. I apologize, I missed to add this part of information.  So Users should be able to EDIT their version and Reconcile & post to VARIANT ONLY.

Please edit your question post to include this information.  The question doesn't make sense without it.

So after some research with analyst team, It turned out that Feature Class wasn't VERSION ENABLED. after making this change from ArcMap prod, user edits were going as expected.
